# Merge two complex queries of SQL into single

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables, one of the customer's, product_type_1 and product_type_2.

#### Customers

```
| id | name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | Alex  |
| 2  | John  |
| 3  | Ahmad |
| 4  | Sam   |
```

#### product_type_1

```
| id | order_by  | Date
|----|--------------|-------|
| 1  |------ 1 ---- | 2019-03-01
| 2  |------ 2 ----| 2019-03-02
| 3  |------ 2 ----| 2019-03-03
| 4  |------ 3  ----| 2019-03-04
```

#### product_type_2

```
| id | order_by  | Date
|----|--------------|-------|
| 1  |------ 1 ---- | 2019-03-01
| 2  |------ 3 ----| 2019-03-02
| 3  |------ 3 ----| 2019-03-03
| 4  |------ 2  ----| 2019-03-04
```

The final output will be the sum of amount of both product type grouped by name of the customer of each month of a specific year. I have written query but it works for 1 product type at a time. But I want sum of both i.e:

```
Customer | Jan | Feb | Mar .... Total<br>
:------------------------------------------------------:
John  ------   |  0  -- |--- 0   |--- 3  ......  3
```

As John ordered total 3 products in 2019.

The query is

```
select c.name,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 1 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Jan,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 2 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Feb,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 3 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Mar,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 4 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Apr,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 5 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as May,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 6 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Jun,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 7 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Jul,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 8 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Aug,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 9 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Sep,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 10 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Oct,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 11 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Nov,
               sum( month(o.order_date) = 12 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as December,
               count(*) as total
        from customers c join
          (
          select order_by as cID, order_price , order_date
             from orders where year(order_date)=2010
          ) o
        on o.cID = c.id and o.order_price > 0
        group by c.name
        order by total desc
```

Comment: You can group by multiple columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select c.id, c.name,
       sum( month(o.order_date) = 1 and year(o.order_date)=2010) as Jan,
       . . .
from customers c left join
     ((select order_by, date
       from product_type_1
      ) union all
      (select order_by, date
       from product_type_2
      ) 
     ) p12
     on p12.order_by = c.id
group by c.id, c.name
```

Comment: Just for curiosity @Gordon does union all helps in any way as its always the duplicate record that union all outputs as.

Comment: *"does union all helps in any way as its always the duplicate record that union all outputs as"* @HimanshuAhuja does this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kqQvqMT9SWsmxWYU7YAQGX/0) answer your question?

Comment: @Gordon it works but partially. The output have many rows having all columns as null but total shows 1 in total column. Hope you can help.

Comment: Did you mean for selective columns with a different condition? I know the difference between the two union and union all but just that union does the needful in real world scenarios

Comment: My original query mentioned in the question doesn't return null rows. I have no issue if it return null rows but total column some how shows 1. If all are null then how can total can be 1?

Comment: @MohammedHâmzã . . . That is an artifact of the `left join`.  You want `count(p12.order_by)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: Really appreciate your help mate.